# How do I block the IP for those who enter my website twice?

Tags: python, php

I have this code:

```
$accounts = fopen("accounts.txt", "r+");
$give_account = fgets($accounts);
$fileContents = file_get_contents("ips.txt");
fclose($accounts);
    if(strpos($fileContents, $ip) !== false){
        echo $give_account;
    
    }else{
        echo "you have already received an account";
    }
```

i want to get his ip(i got this point),and I want you to receive your account,and I want to delete from the list the account that I gave and not be able to receive another one and print the else.If you can help me with something, even a little, I would appreciate it.Thanks

Comment: You now, that most users (at least when they are private) change there IP dailly automatically from their provider. On the other hand you block with this all users with the same IP like a company or an university.

Comment: If I ask this it is because I know that there will be no company claiming my service

Comment: If one student from the university vistits you, all other students from there will be blocked too. But it's your decision what you want and why you do so.

Comment: What specifically is the issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagining that you do not have any kind of database usage in your website, This code should give you a quick heads up on how to handle your scenario.

**TIP:** Try not to parse files like strings. Instead, use JSON or XML or some kind of markup language.

```
<?php
if(!function_exists('get_client_ip')){
    function get_client_ip() {
        $ipaddress = '';
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']))
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
        else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']))
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']))
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
        else if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        else
            $ipaddress = null;
        return $ipaddress;
    }
}

if(!function_exists('log_ip_address')){
    function log_ip_address($ip, $account_id){
        // Get the JSON object from the IP Logs file and add this IP to the object
        // $ip_logged is true if JSON object is updated. false otherwise
        $ip_logged = true;

        return $ip_logged ? true : false;
    }
}

if(!function_exists('allot_account_to_client')){
    function allot_account_to_client($account_id, $ip){
        if(empty($account_id) || empty($ip)){
            throw new Exception("Parameter missing");
        }
        // Do your magic here and allot an account to your client if he deserves
        $alloted = true;

        // When alloted, remove the current $account_id from the accounts JSON objects so that you won't allot the same account_id to anyone else

        // Log the IP address
        $log = log_ip_address($ip, $account_id);

        // return true only if ip is logged. If IP logging fails, write a mechanism to put back the account_id back to the accounts Array.
        return $log ? true : false;
    }
}

$ip = get_client_ip();
if($ip == null){
    throw new Exception("Unable to get IP. Do you even exist?");
}

// contains an JSON object of IP addresses that an account was taken from and it's details
$list_of_ips = json_decode(file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/logs/ips.json'));

// Contains JSON Array of account_ids
$accounts = json_decode(file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/accounts/available_accounts.json'));

if(isset($list_of_ips[$ip])){
    $taken_on = new DateTime($list_of_ips[$ip]['taken_on']);
    throw new Exception("You already got your account on ".$taken_on->format('m-d-Y H:i:sP'));
}


$available_account_id = $accounts[0];

// If he comes until here, he deserves the account
$alloted = allot_account_to_client($account_id, $ip);

if(!$alloted){
    echo "Unable to allot you an account.";
    exit(0);
}

echo "Your account id is : ".$account_id;
```

?>

## EDIT:

I do not suggest you to use the files located in your server like this as these files are accessible to the user and it compromises whatever you are doing. Use Databases instead.
If you are so determined to use the files, instead of storing the unencrypted data, use some encryption methods to encrypt the data so that at least a normal non techie user would not know what it is.

Comment: WHERE DO I HAVE TO PUT MY IP.TXT. IN ´DOCUMENT ROOT´?

Comment: "DOCUMENT_ROOT" is a variable that a PHP server (Apache or Ngnix) uses which tells the root directory of your server data files.
Consider a local server in your computer. If your server's root directory is "~/Documents/Sites/accountManagement/" and your test.php file is in "/some_dir/" then you can access your test.php file from any file in any directory using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/some_dir/test.php'

Comment: There must be another way without using json and easier but thanks it has helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can write the IPs from the visitor in a local-file on your server. If someone visits your site, read this file either complete as an array in and check with `array_key_exists` if this IP is inside your list (compare with `!== -1` for exists) or read line by line in and check if they are equal.

If the IP is twice then you can make a **redirect** to another site perhaps something like `"Upps, your here again. I only like new vistors"` **or** you just put the whole following code in an **if-block** that it won't be evaluated.

Comment: can you make a little example?